# Algorithm to reorder values in list in Python

Tags: python, algorithm

I have an array of integers say:

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

And two other arrays that define how I should reorder it:

```
A = [1,4,5,7,8]
B = [1,3,4,5,6]
```

A and B have the same size.

I would like to reorder `arr` in a way that the values in `A` come before the values in `B`, but the values that don't show up in either arrays stay in the same place. For example:

```
>>> reorder(arr, A, B)
[1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 3, 6, 9, 10]
```

Comment: Have you tried any kind of solution ?

Comment: Yes, but my solution generates duplicates sometimes

Comment: Please post it.

Comment: How do you solve `arr = [1,2,3,4,5]; A = [5]; B = [1,2,3]`? Is it `[5, 1, 2, 4, 3]`?

Comment: Also, when you say _but the values that don't show up in either arrays stay in the same place_ What do you mean by that ? Literally the same index or their position referenced to other values ?

Comment: I'll post my trial. I just have to adapt from what I was doing. Regarding the other question: sorry, I didn't make it clear that A and B are of the same size. The "4" is there because the "3" becomes "4", the "4" becomes "5" and so on

Comment: @scharette they stay literally in the same index as originally

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> C = iter(A + [b for b in B if b not in A])
>>> [next(C) if e in A+B else e for e in arr]
[1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 3, 6, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a comparison function, and then you can use the usual `sorted` function.

```
from functools import cmp_to_key

arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

A = [1,4,5,7,8]
B = [1,3,4,5,6]


def cmp(x, y):
    if x == y:
        return 0

    index_x = arr.index(x)
    index_y = arr.index(y)

    if x in A and y in A:
        # keep the initial order between x and y
        return index_x - index_y

    if x in A and y in B:
        # x first
        return -1

    if x in B and y in A:
        # y first
        return 1

    # keep the initial order between x and y
    return index_x - index_y


print(sorted(arr, key=cmp_to_key(cmp)))
# [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 3, 6, 9, 10]
```